# qemu running in ssh: how to exit?

Tags: linux, ssh, qemu

I am connected via SSH to a terminal server. On this server I am using

`qemu-system-x86_64 ... -curses`

to run a Command Line based operating system.

How can I terminate the virtual machine?

At the moment, the only option I have, is to open a second SSH console, and type

`killall qemu-system-x86_64`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Hit `ALT-2` instead of CTRL-ALT-2, then type `quit`

This was already kind of answered over here

https://superuser.com/questions/582942/how-can-i-get-qemus-ctrlalt-keys-working-in-curses-mode

Comment: I had to type `ESC+2` instead of `ALT+2`

Answer (score 5):

Following key combination tells qemu to stop emulation and exit

`Ctrl + a x`

Answer (score 3):

What is the "command line based operating system" in use?

For example, if you are running FreeDOS, the command

```
fdapm poweroff
```

will gracefully power off the VM.

If the OS you are using does not have any power off commands, then using the qemu monitor may be the only option.

Answer (score 2):

If you are running with nographic options below option worked for me

step 1:

```
Cntrl + a
```

Step 2

press `c`

Step 3

write `quit`

Answer (score 0):

First press `Ctrl+a` then press `c` to get to qemu console then enter `quit` to exist.

https://nickdesaulniers.github.io/blog/2018/10/24/booting-a-custom-linux-kernel-in-qemu-and-debugging-it-with-gdb/